# Fire passport.js callback after a Database fetch is done

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, mysqljs

I need to redirect a [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) Facebook login to a profile route that renders a [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) view feeding it  the **User** object as well as some additional data (**messages** array) fetched asynchronously from a DB.

Unfortunately, I get this error

> Cannot GET /auth/facebook/callback

Here is my server.js code

```
// Import ExpressJS
let express = require("express");
let app = express();

// Import Body Parser
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Import Express Session Middleware
let session = require("express-session");

// Import EJS template engine
let ejs = require("ejs");

// Import custom middlewares
let flash = require("./middlewares/flash");
let setUser = require("./middlewares/flash");

// Import Message model
let Message = require ("./models/message");

// Import the user model
let User = require("./models/user");

// Import PassportInitializer
let passport = require("./config/passport.js");

// Import keys
let keys = require("./config/keys");

app

// Templating
.set('view engine',"ejs")

//Middlewares

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
.use(bodyParser.json())

//Use middlewares
.use(passport.initialize())
.use(passport.session())

// Set-up and Use Express Session
.use(session({
  secret: keys.session.secret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false }
}))

.use(flash)

//Routes
.use("/assets",express.static("public"))


// Home
.get("/",(req,res)=>{

    Message.all((messages)=>{
        res.render("pages/index",{messages:messages});
    })
})

//Single message
.get("/message/:id",(req,res)=>{
    Message.find(req.params.id,(message)=>{
        if(message===null){
            res.status(400).send('<h1>HTTP Error 400: Bad Request!</h1>');
        } else {
            res.render("messages/show",{message:message});
        }

    });

})

// Facebook OAuth
.get("/auth/facebook/",passport.authenticate("facebook"))

// Facebook OAuth callback
.get('/auth/facebook/callback',passport.authenticate("facebook"),(req,res)=>{
        Message.all((messages)=>{res.send(messages)});

})

// Handle posted/sent message
.post("/",(req,res)=>{
    //If the message body is empty
    if(req.body.message===undefined || req.body.message===""){
        //flash an error message
        req.flash("error","Empty message :(");
        // Redirect to home
        res.redirect("/")
    // If the message body is not empty
    } else {
        // Create a new message and save it.
        Message.create(req.body.message,()=>{
            req.flash("success","Message added :)");
            // Redirect to home
            res.redirect("/");
        }); 
    }
})

// Listen on port
.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

And my message.js file

```
// Import Message model
let connection = require ("../config/db");

// Import Moment Session Middleware
let moment = require("moment");


// Import Message model
let connection = require ("../config/db");

// Import Moment Session Middleware
let moment = require("moment");


class Message{
    constructor(row){
        this.row = row;
    }
    get id(){
        return this.row.id;
    }
    get content(){
        return this.row.content;
    }
    get created_at(){
        return moment(this.row.created_at);
    }

    static all(callback){

        // Get all messages from DB
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM message",(error,results,fields)=>{
            if(error) throw error;

            // Run the callback function once terminated
            callback(results.map((result)=>{
                return new Message(result);
            }));
        });

    }

}

// Export the Message class
module.exports = Message;
// Export the Message class
module.exports = Message;
```

Answer (score 0):

I could figure it out my self, though I do not know if it is a dirty workaround or an acceptable solution.

I had to add a middle-ware which asynchronously fetches the **user** & **messages** data then render the EJS view.

Here is the code

```
//..
// Facebook OAuth
.get("/auth/facebook/",passport.authenticate("facebook"))

// Facebook OAuth callback
.get('/auth/facebook/callback',passport.authenticate("facebook"),(req,res)=>{

})

.use((req,res,next)=>{
    Message.all((messages)=>{
        let userId = req.session.passport.user;
        if(userId){
            User.find(userId,(user)=>{
            res.render("pages/index",{user:user,messages:messages});
        });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
})
//..
```